# Navigating to DNN Module

Tags: c#, url, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, navigateurl

I'm forming a newsletter with links to various html modules within my DNN website. I have access to each of their ModuleID's and I'm wanting to use that to get the url. The current approach (made by a third party developer) worked, but only to a degree. The url's are incorrectly formed when the Modules are located deeper in the website.

For example module located at www.website.com/website/articles.aspx is works fine, but a module located www.website.com/website/articles/subarticles.aspx won't. I know this is because the url is incorrectly formed.

Here's the current code:

```
DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.ModuleController objModCtrlg = new DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.ModuleController();
DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.ModuleInfo dgfdgdg = objModCtrlg.GetModule(ContentMID);
TabController objtabctrll = new TabController();
TabInfo objtabinfoo = objtabctrll.GetTab(tabidfrcontent);
string tabnamefremail= objtabinfoo.TabName;
moduletitlefrEmail = dgfdgdg.ModuleTitle;
string readmorelinkpath = basePath + "/" + tabnamefremail + ".aspx";
```

ContentMID is the current module ID I'm looking at. I've tried to use Globals.NavigateURL, but that always crashes with `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error. Same thing when I use `objtabinfoo.FullUrl` so I'm currently at a loss as to how I get the specific modules URL.

EDIT: Here's some more code as to how the tabId is retrieved.

```
IDictionary<int, TabInfo> dicTabInfo12 = new Dictionary<int, TabInfo>();
ContentMID = Convert.ToInt32(dsNewsList.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ModuleID"]);
dicTabInfo12 = objTabctrl.GetTabsByModuleID(ContentMID);
if (dicTabInfo12.Count > 0)
{
    string tester = ""; //Debug
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, TabInfo> item1 in dicTabInfo12)
    {
        tabidfrcontent = item1.Key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, colleague suggested this and it works great within a scheduler.

```
string linkPath = basePath + "/Default.aspx?TabID=" + tabID;
```

Will Navigate you to the correct tab ID. So this would be the best solution if you're forced to work within a scheduler where you can't use `NavigateUrl` without some major workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

You really should be using NavigateUrl to build the links ance if you have the tabid, you are golden.

```
string readMoreLinkPath = NavigateUrl(tabidfrcontent);
```

Nice and simple

Comment: I'm still getting the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` Which I don't understand why. My only guess is that tabid is maybe wrong. Unfortunately I'm unable to properly debug so I'm relying on messages written out to a text file.

Comment: I just saw this post http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/203/postid/361541/scope/posts.aspx I am using this in a scheduled task so that is probably why I'm getting the error. Question is, how am I going to get and assign the portal settings?